# ReportLab Paragraph Formatting Line Breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pdf, reportlab

I am new to ReportLab and I am creating a simple document where employees enter text into a textarea on a website, it is saved into a DB, and then pulled from the DB to create a PDF via ReportLab. The issue I am seeing is that if a user enters text that contains a line break between 2 paragraphs, that line break is not honored when the PDF is created.

When I print the text content out of the DB directly to the screen via the same Python script, everything is correct:

> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
>   has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
>   it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
>   Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
>   Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
>   through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
>   undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
>   1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
>   theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
>   of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
>   section 1.10.32.
>
> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
>   has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
>   it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
>   Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
>   Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
>   through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
>   undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
>   1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
>   theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
>   of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
>   section 1.10.32.

However, in the PDF it looks like:

> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
>   has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
>   it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
>   Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
>   Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
>   through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
>   undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
>   1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the
>   theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
>   of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
>   section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply
>   random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature
>   from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
>   professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the
>   more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and
>   going through the cites of the word in classical literature,
>   discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections
>   1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise
>   on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The
>   first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
>   a line in section 1.10.32.

At first I thought it was a text formatting issue into the DB, but after I am able to print out the content correctly right before PDF creation I know thats not the problem.

Am I missing a simple style input for the paragraph? I am a little lost since I don't know all the ins and outs of ReportLab yet.

Here is the ReportLab code snippet from the script. `employeeQuestion1` is what prints out in the correct format before the PDF is created.

```
def stylesheet():
    styles= {
        'default': ParagraphStyle(
            'default',
            fontName='SourceSansPro-Bold',
            fontSize=10,
            leading=12,
            leftIndent=0,
            rightIndent=0,
            firstLineIndent=0,
            alignment=TA_LEFT,
            spaceBefore=0,
            spaceAfter=0,
            bulletFontName='Times-Roman',
            bulletFontSize=10,
            bulletIndent=0,
            textColor= black,
            backColor=None,
            wordWrap=None,
            borderWidth= 0,
            borderPadding= 0,
            borderColor= None,
            borderRadius= None,
            allowWidows= 1,
            allowOrphans= 0,
            textTransform=None,
            endDots=None,         
            splitLongWords=1,
        ),
    }
    styles['employee_response'] = ParagraphStyle(
        'employee_response',
        parent=styles['default'],
        fontName='SourceSansPro-Regular',
        fontSize=10,
        spaceAfter=10,
        leftIndent=20
    )
    return styles

def build_flowables(stylesheet):
    return [
        Paragraph('{0}'.format(employeeQuestion1), stylesheet['employee_response']),
    ]

def build_pdf(filename, flowables):
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(filename, 
        rightMargin=inch/2,
        leftMargin=inch/2,
        topMargin=inch/2,
        bottomMargin=inch/2,
        pagesize=letter,
    )

    doc.addPageTemplates(
        [
            PageTemplate(
                frames=[
                    Frame(
                        doc.leftMargin,
                        doc.bottomMargin,
                        doc.width,
                        doc.height,
                        id=None
                    ),
                ]
            ),
        ]
    )
    doc.build(flowables)
    build_pdf('/etc/review_app/reviews/{0}.pdf'.format(pdfFileName), build_flowables(stylesheet()))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by converting new lines to `<br />` tags:

```
str(employeeQuestion1).replace('\n','<br />\n')
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue